# Inserting Nested Object Efficiently

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, bulkinsert

If I have the following schema:

```
class Sinbad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tinbads
  accepts_nested_attributes_for: :tinbads
end

class Tinbad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sinbad
  has_many :pinbads
  accepts_nested_attributes_for: :pinbads
end

class Pinbad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tinbad
end
```

and it's not uncommon for a `Tinbad` to have a few hundred `Pinbads`, is there a common way to create a nested `Sinbad` without invoking hundreds of queries?

I've come to the sad understanding that Active Record doesn't support batch inserts but is there a way around this that doesn't involve handwritten SQL? I've looked at https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import, but it doesn't support nested objects. Currently, the `SinbadController#create` action averages `>400` insert transactions and it's the most common action used.

Here's an example of what I want not to happen:
https://gist.github.com/adamkuipers/12578343d31a651bee4a

Instead of inserting into the `photos` table N times, I want to insert only once.

Comment: have you tried using an array of nested hashes? i think it should work as long as the web server supports that amount of data sent in a post request

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, I'm not sure I understand. I'm only creating a single `Sinbad` in the controller but active record generates a separate `insert` for each nested attribute, and recursively generates insert statement for those attribute's nested attributes.

Comment: well isn't that logical, it's different tables

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Right, that's not what I mean though. I'm talking about multiple inserts for row's of the same table. If there is a `Sinbad` with 40 `Tinbad`s, I want there to be two inserts not 41 inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem. I'm parsing big spreadsheets and the schema used to store the data is nested, so I'm inserting only a single "`Sinbad`" but thousands of "`Pinbad`" can get inserted at once...

What I came up to speed up the insert is to bulk insert the bottom leaves of the schema (visualize the schema as a tree), as this must be the model with the highest amount of instances to create - in your case, the Pinbad instances. We cannot bulk insert middle leaves as bulk insert doesn't allow to fetch the ids of the multiplie models inserted (see discussion [here](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/PATCH-Enforce-that-INSERT-RETURNING-preserves-the-order-of-multi-rows-td5728579.html) concerning postgresql for instance). So it's not ideal, but that's the only way I found to make the inserts more efficient (without changing the schema itself).

You'll have to remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as you need to save the objects yourself, and it's convenient to use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) for the bulk insert:

```
class Sinbad
  #
  # Let's imagine you still receive the params as if you were using accepts_nested_attributes,
  # Meaning :pinbads_attributes will be nested under :tinbads_attributes
  # that will be nested under :sinbad
  #
  def self.efficient_create params
    # I think AR doesn't like when attributes doesn't exist,
    # so we should keep the tinbads attributes somewhere else 
    tinbads_attributes = params[:tinbads_attributes]
    params.delete :tinbads_attributes
    sinbad = self.create! params

    # Array that will contain the attributes of the pinbads to bulk insert
    pinbads_to_save = []
    # ActiveRecords-Import needs to know which cols of Pinbad you insert
    pinbads_cols = [:tinbad_id, :name, :other]

    # We need to manually save the tinbads one by one,
    # but that's what happen when using accepts_nested_attributes_for
    tinbads_attributes.each do |attrs|
      pinbads_attribute = attrs[:pinbads_attributes]
      attrs.delete :pinbads_attibutes
      tinbad = sinbad.tinbads.create! attrs

      pinbads_attributes.each do |p_attrs|
        # Take care to put the attributes
        # in the same order than the pinbad_cols array
        pinbads_to_save << [tinbad.id, p_attrs[:name], p_attrs[:other]]
      end
    end

    # Now we can bulk insert the pinbads, using activerecord-import
    Pinbad.import_without_validations_or_callbacks pinbad_cols, pinbads_to_save
  end
end
```

That's what I've done in my situation and as the last level in the schema hierarchy has the most instances to create, the overall insert time was greatly reduced. In your case, you would replace the ~400 inserts of Pinbad with 1 bulk insert.

Hope that helps, and I'm open to any suggestion or alternative solution!